Yahweh is Yama?
and their god “Yahweh” bears much resemblance to and is likely derived from Deva Yama, the Hindu Lord of Death and Hell
In other words, over the course of the development of the Abrahamic religions, Yama, the Hindu Lord of Death and Hell, was rendered as “God” (Hebrew Yahweh)
And indeed, it seems likely along those same strands of the mythological narrative and reasoning that Yahweh was in fact Yama
Essentially, Yahweh, worshiped by Jews and Christians as “God,” is actually the being knew as the Lord of Hell!!
A description of Lord Yama that sounds rather like the "Judgement Seat" of "God" the Christians talk about, no?

Just like how Brahman is related to Abraham?

Isn’t Brahman also Yama ? ‘mrityuve Swaha, Mrityuve Swaha, om namo Mrityuve Mrityur Mae Pahi’ from Namakam / Shri Rudram is an epithet of Brahman isn’t it?

Doesn’t Hell exist in the Lord ? Doesn’t he live in hell ? Doesn’t he live in Heaven? Doesn’t he live every where? Isn’t anything. alive..Him ? Ha ? Isn’t that Brahman ? Life itself.. Sentience ? ( Psst: I’m leaving out Parahbrahman why? )
